# Python class can't see method unless I comment out __init__

Tags: python

The following code only works if I comment out the initialiser.

```
class What:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        print 'method1'

def main():
    b = What()

    if hasattr(b,"method1"):
        print "b.method1"

    b.method1()

main()
```

If it's not commented out I get the error message…

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strange.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "strange.py", line 15, in main
    b.method1()
AttributeError: What instance has no attribute 'method1'
```

However if I type in an identical method and call it, there is no problem at all…

```
    def method2(self):
        print 'method2'
```

I've od -c the file and there are no strange characters in the text
Using Python 2.7.2

Comment: Something else is going on, as this works fine, as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you are mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: @sberry Correct. I tested this with Python 2.7.3 and it works fine.

Comment: I don't think its relevant to the issue you're having, but its worth noting that your `What` class is an "old-style" class. Old-style classes are deprecated in Python 2, and you should create "new-style" classes instead (unless you have a very good reason for it). To get a new-style class, inherit from `object` (or some other new-style class), e.g. `class What(object):` New-style classes are the default in Python 3!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mixing tabs and spaces.

With the code using 4 spaces per indent (spaces in accordance with pep8) it works fine.  But this

```
class What:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

        def method1(self):
            print 'method1'

def main():
    b = What()

    if hasattr(b,"method1"):
        print "b.method1"

    b.method1()

main()
```

Is what Python would see if you had tabs for method1, and this will generate the error you see.

Comment: I was about to answer this. If you check the code that the OP has pasted into SO, there are a mix of tabs and spaces. Good call!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I didn't even realize that SO code paste retained the tabs.  Nice to know, and confirmed as well.

Comment: Also, is `def method1` meant to be indented so far? Its in the `__init__` block at the moment.

Comment: @Stormtroopr, thats the whole point - python sees the `method1` method as a function defined inside `__init__` method.